# What is the idea of a good random numbers generator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, numbers

I am writing a program for card games. There can be several game players (say, from 2 to 7). A deck consists of 54 cards. I need to distribute/deal cards to the players randomly.

We can consider the deck of 54 cards as a char array of 54 elements. Let us suppose that in a certain game each player must be given with 6 cards. The number of players is 2. So, it is necessary to generate two arrays, each of them consists of 6 elements selected from a "big" array of 54 elements. Moreover, in those two generated arrays there should not be shared/duplicate elements.

I tried a recursive algorithm to obtain a sequence of *m* unique random numbers from 0 to (m - 1).

X(n+1) = (a * X(n) + c) mod m

You need to set the parameters:

- m -- module, m > 0
- a -- factor, 0 <= a < m
- c -- increment, 0 <= c < m
- X(0) -- initial value , 0 <= X(0) < m
- Numbers *c* and *m* must be coprime.
- *(a - 1)* is divisible by *p* for each prime *p* that is a divisor of *m*
- If *m* is divisible by 4 then *(a - 1)* must be divisible by 4.

Here's the code for this algorithm. As you can see, the parameters a, c, m and X(0) satisfy the mentioned conditions.

```
int a = 13,
    c = 11,
    m = 54, // because the total number of cards is 54
    x0 = 1;

int x[100];
x[0] = x0;
cout << x[0] << "  ";

for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
{
    x[i] = (a * x[i - 1] + c) % m;
    cout << x[i] << "  ";
}
```

The result is: 1  24  53  52  39  32  49  0  11  46  15  44  43  30  23  40  45  2  37  6  35 34  21  14  31  36  47  28  51  26  25  12  5  22  27  38  19  42  17  16  3  50
  13  18  29  10  33  8  7  48  41  4  9  20. Do you think it is random?

What can you say about this algorithm? In general, what should be the idea of ​​a random distribution of cards for each player?

You see, if I integrate this algorithm to my program, it will deal the same sequence of cards as it is shown above each time you launch the program (because the parameters do not change). So I will need to change a, m, c and X(0) between launches of my program. Then I will have another problem: how to set these parameters automatically (and randomly, too) so that they satisfy the necessary conditions (see the bulleted list above).

Comment: Have a peruse at the one available for boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

Comment: @DumbCoder Thank you for the link. What can you say about my approach? Is this too simple so that it will not generate good random numbers?

Comment: Your output be the same in the second run and it becomes predictable. Have you looked at `random_shuffle` in the STL algorithm.

Comment: shuffling the array (with `std::random_shuffle` or `std::shuffle`) is simpler. Then draw card in order.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to shuffle the deck of cards. I did not know there was such a possibility to shuffle an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me like you're making an unnecessarily complex system.

A much simpler approach is to create an array of all of your elements, *shuffle* it, and then just remove elements one at a time.

A simple and efficient way of shuffling is to use a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
//Initialize an array/vector/etc. with all the possible values
for (int i = NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  //Pick a random integer j between 0 and i (inclusive)
  //Swap elements i and j
}
```

Now, you can just iterate through the shuffled array, picking the next element every time you need a new card.

```
int pos = 0; //The position of the next card in the deck
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS; j++)
  {
    player[j].addCard(deck[pos++])
  }
}
```

Ideally, you would probably want to wrap some of this into classes, but I've left that out for brevity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Fisher-Yates shuffle is the same to std::random_shuffle and std::shuffle?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot guarantee randomness the way you put it. It is a generated sequence with low informational enthropy - in other words it is easily hacked.
You can simply use standard rand() from stdlib http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/.

I'd recommend using mt19937 comes with std in c++11 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/ or boost one as mentioned in comments.

Comment: Yes, I also think my approach does not guarantee randomness. Did you calculated the entropy using the possibilities of cards occurrence? I have not heard about mt19937. I will read about the function. Thank you for the reply and information.

Comment: I didn't calculate the enthropy, but by given generated sequence the formula can be deducted simply by bruteforce.

Answer (score 1):

another way to do it, could be to randomize the action of taking a card instead of a shuffle the container.

something like this :

```
// first step
// init and fill container
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 54; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);

// second step
// take a random card
srand(time(NULL)); // init seed
int i = std::rand() % v.size();
int card = v[i]; // get card
v.erase(vec.begin() + i); // remove card from deck
return card;
```

for the second step, you need `<ctime>` and `<cstdlib>`. I am not sure it is better than the other solution. Just my two cents.